# Sample code for Interface Builder to create UI like Preview.app?

Tags: macos, interface-builder

I've seen several programs which use a UI which looks just like Preview's. I want to do the same thing, so, I figure that there is probably some sample code somewhere that shows how to do that. I don't really need the "customize toolbar" option, although that would be cool. I more just want to know how to get Interface Builder to generate the correct Nibs for the default interface...

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably just need to work your way through the examples located in 
/Developer/Examples/AppKit/

at it's essence Preview.app is not much more than a window with a scrollable content view, plus a toolbar and a drawer.  However, in many ways it is a tour-de-force of the capabilities of the AppKit (drag'n'drop, hierarchical menus, context menus, spotlight, textedit, userdefaults, rulers, even the kitchen sink, you get the idea...)

play with the appKit examples, you'll be glad you did!

Comment: The "customize toolbar" behavior is free, by the way.